# Папка cache в админке сайта на Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Добрый вечер! И снова я со своими таинственными расследованиями новичка. Очень прошу прощения, если они кого-то раздражают и кажутся бесполезными, но обратиться за профессиональным советом больше не к кому.

Ситуация. На двух страницах (может и больше,но при беглом рэндомном просмотре, больше нигде такой проблемы не обнаружилось)сайта подвал перестал занимать 100% ширины и прижиматься к нижнему краю страницы и подступил к самому контенту.

Логически такого не должно быть же? Сайт на Битриксе и на всех страницах шаблон и стили для футера одинаковые. Изучив код с помощью инструмента браузера Опера заметила, что он показывает стиль основной, на который ссылается шаблон (main.css), а ниже еще один стиль для футера. Именно такой кривой, как и выглядит сейчас на странице. Ссылается на некий файл template 89...855 в папке bitrix -> cache.

В этой папке большое количество этих файлов template. И возник ряд вопросов.

По какой причине на этой странице футер стал обращаться к этому файлу стилей?
Можно ли без негативных последствий для сайта удалить этот файл?
Можно ли вообще отчистить папку cache и повлияет ли это на увеличение скорости загрузки сайта? По последнему вопросу не нашла полноценной достоверной информации.

Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 1):

Папку cache можно безболезненно очистить. Битрикс начнет генерировать в неё файлы кэша заново, так что это бесполезно.

Файлы стилей в эту папку попадают потому, что в настройках главного модуля включено объединение и/или сжатие CSS. Можно выключить, тогда CSS будут браться напрямую из шаблонов сайта/компонентов.

Comment: Т.е. очистка этой папки никак не повлияет на скорость работы сайта? И если я удалю конкретно тот стилевой файл,то страница снова будет ссылаться на main.css?

Comment: Повлияет, т.к. Битрикс будет создавать эти файлы заново. Но если выключить объединение и сжатие CSS, то никак не повлияет. Аналогично страница будет ссылаться на основной main.css только в том случае, если в настройках главного модуля выключено объединение и сжатии CSS.

Comment: Повлияет в сторону замедления или ускорения работы сайта? И где конкретно располагается эта настройка объединения и сжатия CSS? И какую ощутимую практическую пользу несет эта настройка?